# Fill page with stackpanels from top to bottom, even if a stackpanel is disabled

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I made a C# store app. Now i have stackpanels that are collapsed if the textblock inside that stackpanel does not contain data. But now i want the stackpanels to automatically fill from top to bottom. If a stackpanel with no data gets collapsed, the stackpanel below the collapsed stackpanel should move up and fill from top to bottom again (so i won't get any empty spaces).

A piece of code about my stackpanels:

```
        <StackPanel x:Name="STACKActualStockDeliverTime" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="550,150,0,0">
            <Border>

                <TextBlock OpticalMarginAlignment="None">
                    <Run x:Name="HEADERActualStockDeliverTime" FontSize="24" Text="Voorraad en levertijd"></Run><LineBreak/>
                    <Run x:Name="TXTActualStock" FontSize="18" Text="Actuele voorraad: "></Run><LineBreak/>
                    <Run x:Name="TXTInPuraseOrder" FontSize="18" Text="Aantal in inkooporders: "></Run><LineBreak/>
                    <Run x:Name="TXTInSalesOrder" FontSize="18" Text="Aantal in verkooporders: "></Run><LineBreak/>
                    <Run x:Name="TXTDeliverTime" FontSize="18" Text="Levertijd: "></Run>
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#88287d37" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="400" />
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="125" />
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel  x:Name="STACKActualStockDeliverTime2"  Orientation="Vertical" Margin="750,188,0,0">      
            <Border>
                <TextBlock OpticalMarginAlignment="None">
                    <Run x:Name="BINDActualStock" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding ActualStock}"/><LineBreak/>
                    <Run x:Name="BINDInPuraseOrder" FontSize="18" Text="4"/><LineBreak/>
                    <Run x:Name="BINDInSalesOrder" FontSize="18" Text="12"/><LineBreak/>
                    <Run x:Name="BINDDeliverTime" FontSize="18" Text="2 weken"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="STACKPrices" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="550,295,0,0">
            <Border>
                <TextBlock OpticalMarginAlignment="None">
                    <Run x:Name="HEADERPrices" FontSize="24" Text="Prijzen"></Run><LineBreak/>
                    <Run x:Name="TXTPurasePrice" FontSize="18" Text="Inkoopprijs: "></Run><LineBreak/>
                    <Run x:Name="TXTSalesPrice" FontSize="18" Text="Verkoopprijs: "></Run><LineBreak/>
                    <Run x:Name="TXTMargin" FontSize="18" Text="Marge: "></Run>
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel x:Name="STACKPrices2" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="750,335,0,0">
            <Border>
                <TextBlock OpticalMarginAlignment="None">
                    <Run x:Name="BINDPurchasePrice" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding PurchasePrice}"></Run><LineBreak/>
                    <Run x:Name="BINDUnitPriceEXCLVAT" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding UnitPriceExclVAT}"></Run><LineBreak/>
                    <Run x:Name="BINDMargin" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Margin}"></Run>
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel x:Name="STACKExtraInfo" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="550,420,0,0">
            <Border>
                <TextBlock OpticalMarginAlignment="None">
                    <Run x:Name="HEADERExtraInfo" FontSize="24" Text="Extra informatie"></Run><LineBreak/>
                    <Run x:Name="TXTStatus" FontSize="18" Text="Status: "></Run><LineBreak/>
                    <Run x:Name="TXTBlocked" FontSize="18" Text="Geblokkeerd: "></Run>
                </TextBlock>

            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="STACKExtraInfo2" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="750,460,0,0">
            <Border>
                <TextBlock OpticalMarginAlignment="None">
                   <Run x:Name="BINDStatus" FontSize="18" Text="vrijgegeven"></Run><LineBreak/>
                   <Run x:Name="BINDBlocked" FontSize="18" Text="nee"></Run>
                </TextBlock>

            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
```

sorry for the long piece of code but that would make it clear what i'm doing i guess?

Hope you can give me a hint how to solve my problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok will do, thought it might be necessary for an answer. //done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you wrap all the stackpanels in one wrapper `StackPanel`.

Note Ive removed the Height from the first border as the Panels below wont be able to move up with this set Height.

Ive removed `Orientation="Vertical"` as StackPanel has this setting by default

Also Ive removed your margins so you may have to play around with those again but placing items using Margins in that manner is not a good idea due to varying screen sizes of devices

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <StackPanel x:Name="STACKActualStockDeliverTime">
            <Border>

                <TextBlock OpticalMarginAlignment="None">
                <Run x:Name="HEADERActualStockDeliverTime" FontSize="24" Text="Voorraad en levertijd"></Run><LineBreak/>
                <Run x:Name="TXTActualStock" FontSize="18" Text="Actuele voorraad: "></Run><LineBreak/>
                <Run x:Name="TXTInPuraseOrder" FontSize="18" Text="Aantal in inkooporders: "></Run><LineBreak/>
                <Run x:Name="TXTInSalesOrder" FontSize="18" Text="Aantal in verkooporders: "></Run><LineBreak/>
                <Run x:Name="TXTDeliverTime" FontSize="18" Text="Levertijd: "></Run>
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#88287d37" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="400" />
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel  x:Name="STACKActualStockDeliverTime2" >
            <Border>
                <TextBlock OpticalMarginAlignment="None">
                <Run x:Name="BINDActualStock" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding ActualStock}"/><LineBreak/>
                <Run x:Name="BINDInPuraseOrder" FontSize="18" Text="4"/><LineBreak/>
                <Run x:Name="BINDInSalesOrder" FontSize="18" Text="12"/><LineBreak/>
                <Run x:Name="BINDDeliverTime" FontSize="18" Text="2 weken"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel x:Name="STACKExtraInfo2" Margin="0,20,0,0">
            <Border>
                <TextBlock OpticalMarginAlignment="None">
                   <Run x:Name="BINDStatus" FontSize="18" Text="vrijgegeven"></Run><LineBreak/>
                   <Run x:Name="BINDBlocked" FontSize="18" Text="nee"></Run>
                </TextBlock>

            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <StackPanel x:Name="STACKPrices">
                <Border>
                    <TextBlock OpticalMarginAlignment="None">
                    <Run x:Name="HEADERPrices" FontSize="24" Text="Prijzen"></Run><LineBreak/>
                    <Run x:Name="TXTPurasePrice" FontSize="18" Text="Inkoopprijs: "></Run><LineBreak/>
                    <Run x:Name="TXTSalesPrice" FontSize="18" Text="Verkoopprijs: "></Run><LineBreak/>
                    <Run x:Name="TXTMargin" FontSize="18" Text="Marge: "></Run>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel x:Name="STACKPrices2">
                <Border>
                    <TextBlock OpticalMarginAlignment="None">
                    <Run x:Name="BINDPurchasePrice" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding PurchasePrice}"></Run><LineBreak/>
                    <Run x:Name="BINDUnitPriceEXCLVAT" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding UnitPriceExclVAT}"></Run><LineBreak/>
                    <Run x:Name="BINDMargin" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Margin}"></Run>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel x:Name="STACKExtraInfo" >
                <Border>
                    <TextBlock OpticalMarginAlignment="None">
                    <Run x:Name="HEADERExtraInfo" FontSize="24" Text="Extra informatie"></Run><LineBreak/>
                    <Run x:Name="TXTStatus" FontSize="18" Text="Status: "></Run><LineBreak/>
                    <Run x:Name="TXTBlocked" FontSize="18" Text="Geblokkeerd: "></Run>
                    </TextBlock>

                </Border>
            </StackPanel>

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**EDIT** added a 2 column grid to help position items. Both columns are `Width="1*"` which means each column will take up 50% of the available screen. Use smaller margins on the StackPanels to adjust. Hope it helps

Comment: Whats the best way to set stackpanels on a particular place on the page?

Comment: This is the correct answer by the way. Except for the fact that the stackpanels arn't in place right now because i removed the margins :)

Comment: ah let me have a look at your original code. will edit to try and replicate :)